# What are Python disassemblers used for?

Tags: python, disassembly

I've noticed there is a significant degree of interest in Python disassemblers such as the `dis` module.

However it is surprisingly difficult to find what these disassemblers are generally used for in industry/academia. Outside of satisfying curiosity (a perfectly legitimate endeavour!) or writing Python implementations do they have any common uses?

Comment: No (in my opinion) :-)

Comment: @ArminRigo Could you put that down as an answer? Looks like you're right and I'd like to accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Python bytecode disassembler has no common use aside from curiosity or investigating details of the Python implementations.  It's similar to how most C programmers never need to look at assembler, even though they are compiling C code to assembler and using debuggers like gdb.  In Python's case, pdb (but also tracebacks and so on) all nicely hide the bytecode from the regular programmer's eyes.

Of course, it can be fun to learn about it anyway.  It's one way of getting a good idea about how Python really works :-)

Answer (score 2):

There is a practical use for disassmblers, although it's a very rare case that I'm just metioning for the sake of completeness: when you're optimizing code where and you want to check if writing your code differently can make it faster.  This is only relevant for code where speed is of great importance.  You normally don't need to worry about these kind of low-level optimizations.

For example, the CPython compiler optimizes expressions containing only literals, turning something like `'foo' + 'bar'` into `'foobar'` at compile time.  This might not be the same for other Python implementations, so the best way to check whether the compiler optimizes this is to use a disassembler:

```
>>> import dis
>>> def f():
...     return 'foo'+'bar', 3*100, 'spam'*2
...
>>> dis.dis(f)
  2           0 LOAD_CONST               9 (('foobar', 300, 'spamspam'))
              3 RETURN_VALUE
```

Comment: Given that it *only* works if you use literals, it's of limited use. For example, `return 'spam'*N` where N is a global constant is still not foldable.  I believe that the bytecode compiler does (and can do) only a few optimizations that are not very useful in practice.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to look for a line of code in a machine language program, such as one causing an annoying popup or a piece of malware, a disassembler might help you find the piece of  toxic code.

Also,as Flornquake says, programs assembled by higher order languages like Python are sometimes not  efficient.  If you need a high speed program, say to read fast data coming from an outside device, you may well need to go into the assembled code and adjust it for maximum speed.  An example might be digitizing a 20KHz music signal.